# Sphere homeomorphic to interval times space

Tags: general-topology, spheres

Let $Y$ be any topological space. In my notes I found the exercise to show that: $I \times Y \approx S^n $ via a homeomorphism is not possible, where $S^n$ denotes the $n$-sphere and $I$ the unit interval.

It is used in the proof of the Jordan curve theorem, so maybe a proof without using this theorem would be appropriate.

Obviously $Y \simeq I \times Y \approx S^n$, hence $Y \simeq S^n  $, but I guess this does not get me any further.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is $\simeq$ mean there? Homeomorphic? homotopic?

Comment: $\approx$ should denote homeomorphic and homotopic is denoted by $\simeq$ in this case

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand the question, but does $I$ denote $[0,1]$ or $(0,1)$? If the former (the standard use of the notation $I$), this is clear since $\mathbb{S}^n$ has no boundary (whereas $I\times Y$ does), and in the latter, this is also clear since $I\times Y$ is not compact.

Comment: Thank you, I meant the former definition. The boundary reason absolutely makes sense to me, because boundaries are mapped to boundaries via a homeomorphism. But is this true for any domain and target space? For Euclidean spaces or manifolds it makes sense to me.

Comment: @Amitesh: $Y$ is just a topological space, not a manifold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this were true, the sphere would also be homeomorphic to $[0,1/2] \times Y$, and hence you would have a subspace of $S^n$ homeomorphic to $S^n$ that isn't the whole space. This is impossible by [invariance of domain](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain). I'm sure there's a more elementary proof in the case $n=1$, but I expect $n>1$ probably wants a homological proof like this.

Of course, the same proof shows that $I \times Y$ cannot ever be homeomorphic to a closed manifold.